# How to create my own substring method in JS?

Tags: javascript

Im trying create my own substring method in JS

```
function substr(string, p1 = 0, p2 = string.length) {
  if (string.length === 0 || p2 < 0 || p1 > p2) return '';
  const p11 = p1 <= 0 ? 0 : p1
  let p22 = p2 > string.length ? string.length : p2
  const str = string.split('').reduce((acc, item, i) => {
    if (i >= p11 && i < p22) {
      console.log('i:', i)
      return acc.concat(item)
    }
    return acc
  }, '');

  console.log('inside', str)
  return str
}
```

when Im test this code I have an error

```
expect(substr('abba', 1, 0)).toEqual(''); // pass
expect(substr('abba', 0, 1)).toEqual('a'); // pass
expect(substr('abba', 0, 1)).toEqual('a'); // pass
expect(substr('abba', 1, 2)).toEqual('bb'); // failed
```

How I can fix my code to pass tests?

Comment: `return string.slice(p1, p2)`

Comment: Which means that - heck - you don't need to implement "my own substring method". Just use `slice`.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb Supposedly it's an exercise? Using `slice` or any thing similar is probably considered "cheating" as it would greatly simplify the code.

Comment: Is `p2` supposed to be the length of the substring, or the final (excluded) position?

Comment: @Nick: This dude is using `split` and `concat`, so what difference could `slice` possibly make?

Comment: @Nick: the length of the substring, according to the `failed` example, and the final excluded position according to (probably) what he/she wants to achieve.

Comment: @Mina The fourth shoud be `bb`, because original js subtring method gives `bb`

Comment: I think that this partially belongs to Software engineering SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is your code example:

```js
     1 function substr(string, p1 = 0, p2 = string.length) {
     2    if (string.length === 0 || p2 < 0 || p1 > p2) return '';
     3    const p11 = p1 <= 0 ? 0 : p1
     4    let p22 = p2 > string.length ? string.length : p2
     5    const str = string.split('').reduce((acc, item, i) => {
     6      if (i >= p11 && i < p22) {
     7        console.log('i:', i)
     8        return acc.concat(item)
     9      }
    10      return acc
    11    }, '');
    12
    13    console.log('inside', str)
    14    return str
    15  }
```

There are multiple mistakes in your code. You are still learning. That's no problem – everyone has started somehow. Let's name the mistakes:

- On the line 2, there is `p1 > p2`. That does not make sense. You do not want to return empty string if the distance between string start and the substring start is greater that the maximum substring length.
- Your variable names do not make sense. Try using names like `startpos` or `length` instead of names like `p1` or `p2`.
- And the third thing I found is that your substring function returns substring between positions `p1` and `p2`, unlike the JS's builtin `String.prototype.substr` which returns substring between `p1` and `p1+p2`.

---

Try it this way:

```js
function substr(string, start, length = string.length) {
  let outStr = '';
  for (let pos = start;
       pos < start + length && pos < string.length;
       pos++) {
    outStr += string[pos];
  }
  return outStr;
}

function expect(actual) {
  return {
    'toEqual': function (expected) {
      if (actual == expected) {
        document.body.innerText += `“${actual}” == “${expected}” (pass)\n`;
      } else {
        document.body.innerText += `“${actual}” /= “${expected}” (fail)\n`;
      }
    },
  };
}

expect(substr('abba', 1, 0)).toEqual('');
expect(substr('abba', 0, 1)).toEqual('a');
expect(substr('abba', 0, 1)).toEqual('a');
expect(substr('abba', 1, 2)).toEqual('bb');
```

I think that using split and reduce for this is overkill. But if you want to use it, there is the code in the “pure functional style”, but it is inefficient, because it needs `string.length` steps instead of `length` steps to compute the result.

```js
function substr(string, start, length = string.length) {
  return string
    .split('') // split between every character
    .reduce((head, char, index) =>
      (index >= start && head.length < length) // if we reached the substring start and there “is space” in the substring,
      ? head + char                           // append another character
      : head,                                 // else keep the substring
      ''); // start with empty substring
}

function expect(actual) {
  return {
    'toEqual': function (expected) {
      if (actual == expected) {
        document.body.innerText += `“${actual}” == “${expected}” (pass)\n`;
      } else {
        document.body.innerText += `“${actual}” /= “${expected}” (fail)\n`;
      }
    },
  };
}

expect(substr('abba', 1, 0)).toEqual('');
expect(substr('abba', 0, 1)).toEqual('a');
expect(substr('abba', 0, 1)).toEqual('a');
expect(substr('abba', 1, 2)).toEqual('bb');
```

You should also have better test cases. *Write test cases as if wou would teach someone to use your routines.* The test cases can be important for understanding complex code. For example, take you favorite sentence and test the function using it. It will be easier to understand the test case the next time you see the code.